# Inline two elements using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to inline two elements next to each other using flexbox. I want this to work exactly like `display: inline` works but for flexbox. How would you do this? What am I missing? :)

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/24duh8wr/

Comment: Just change the direction. With flexbox you can set a direction and align or not your items. Use `flex-direction`:`column` | `row`

Comment: that's not what I am asking for. I want the text to wrap with the date, instead it ignores it and works like inline-block would.

Comment: If i add a inline-block in your example i've the same render as flex-direction:column...

Comment: inline, not inline-block.

Comment: Same result as inline too ;-). Please explain better what you want.

Comment: No.. It will wrap with the date https://jsfiddle.net/tt2xh6az/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text in the second item to wrap *around* the text it the first item, flexbox is not the way to achieve this. You have two options (remove `display: flex` from the container in both cases):

1) Just make them inline:

```
.item {
  display: inline;
}
```

2) Float the first item left:

```
.item:first-child {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it with flexbox, if I understand your expectation http://take.ms/sLdMr . Flexbox is tool to build layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please try `display: inline-flex;`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the commentary. Use `flex-direction`.

```css
.flexbox {display: inline;}
.flexbox2{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item">Date:</div>
  <div class="item">Quisque rutrum. Vivamus laoreet. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Curabitur turpis. Morbi ac felis.In ut quam vitae odio lacinia tincidunt. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Sed hendrerit. Nunc egestas, augue at pellentesque laoreet, felis eros vehicula leo, at malesuada velit leo quis pede. Praesent nonummy mi in odio.</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="flexbox2">
  <div class="item">Date:</div>
  <div class="item">Quisque rutrum. Vivamus laoreet. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Curabitur turpis. Morbi ac felis.In ut quam vitae odio lacinia tincidunt. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Sed hendrerit. Nunc egestas, augue at pellentesque laoreet, felis eros vehicula leo, at malesuada velit leo quis pede. Praesent nonummy mi in odio.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not what I am asking for. I guess flexbox can't make this one happen. ty anyway...

Comment: I don't undestand too.

Comment: why would you say .flexbox {display: inline}?? it's the items that should be displayed inline. try this .flexbox .item {display: inline}. I showed you with my fiddle above.